# 'Members' Object reference not set to instance of an object

Tags: .net, webforms

Given an ASP.NET WebForms application and the following (condensed to relevant references only), how do I fix the Object reference not set to instance of an object when I trigger a PostBack event?

UserControl Code-Behind:

```
namespace UserControls.Core
{
    using ...
    
    public partial class MemberDetails : PortalControl
    {
        protected List<Member> Members;
        
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Members = new List<Member>()
                {
                    new Member(1, "John Paul", "Jones"),
                    new Member(2, "Henry", "Avery")
                }
            }
        }
        
        protected void btnEditMember_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var members = Members; // null
            int id = int.Parse(txtSelectedId.Value);
            
            // Exception thrown here
            // Object reference not set to an instance of an object
            Member member = members.Where(i => i.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnEditMember"
    CssClass="btn btn-item-control text-muted"
    OnClientClick="return btnSelectMember_Click(2);"
    OnClick="btnEditMember_Click">
    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Why is it `Members` is `null` in the `btnEditMember_Click()` event? I'm not super familiar with this legacy type of application, I'm still learning the ins and outs of WebForms. Do I have to assign `Members` a value either at declaration or outside of the `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web applications are stateless.  Every time the page is posted back to the server, an entirely new instance of the class (page, control, etc.) is created.  And `Members` is by default `null` when an instance of the class is created:

```
protected List<Member> Members;
```

Currently you only populate it on the initial page load, when `IsPostBack` is `false`.  If you want to populate it on every page request, remove that logic from the `if (!IsPostBack)` condition and always perform that initialization of `Members`.

Note of course also that if you have logic which *modifies* `Members`, those modifications will be lost on post-back.  To retain that state you'd need to store it somewhere.  Session state, a database, a file, wherever you like.

When using Web Forms, it's always a good idea to reference the [ASP.NET PAge Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)).

Comment: Understood. I'll read up on that document to get more familiar. Thanks.